# Matplotlib's colormap is not being applied to scatter plot, no error is returned

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm building a simple scatter plot that reads data from a xls file. 
Instead of "manually" setting the colors for each distinct value I want to use one of the colormaps matplotlib [provides](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html) ("viridis" for instance).

According to some examples I've found on the Internet, I wrote the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

data = pd.read_excel('sample.xls', sheet_name=0)
data.head()

plt.scatter(x = data['ExpecVida'],
        y = data['PIBperCapita'],
        s = data['PopX1000'],
        cmap=cm.viridis)

plt.show()
```

When I run this code on Spyder no error is returned. However, this is the result:

[image: Scatter plot with no colormap]

Everything is still in that default shade of blue. 
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html):

> cmap : Colormap, optional, default: None
>
> A Colormap instance or registered colormap name. **cmap is only used if c is an array of floats**. If None, defaults to rc image.cmap.

So add the parameter c:

```
# Create dummy data:
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,3), columns=['ExpecVida', 'PIBperCapita', 'PopX1000'])

plt.scatter(x=data['ExpecVida'],
            y=data['PIBperCapita'],
            s=data['PopX1000']*1000,
            c=data['PopX1000'],
            cmap=cm.viridis)
```

[image: Graph output]

*(Note I only multiplied s by 1000 so that the dots wouldn't be ridiculously small since my data is nothing but randoms in the range 0-1)*